3D graph - issues filling space between curves and xy-plane
So I have a bunch of datasets stored in several .dat files that I have drawn on a 3D graph to show the data evolution according to a third parameter. In order to make the graph prettier, I would like to fill the space between each curve and the xy-plane. Please note that I am using tikz and pgf plot, and here is my MWE :
\documentclass[10pt,fleqn,french]{article}          %
  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                         %
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}                     %
\usepackage{graphicx,float}                         %
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}                                   %
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,plotmarks,3d}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}                               %
\usepgfmodule{plot}                                 %
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}                           %
                                                    %
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={             %
                    label style={font=\tiny},       %
                    tick label style={font=\tiny},  %
                    legend style={font=\tiny}       %
                    }}                              %

  
\pagecolor{white}
\color{black}

%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~%
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~%
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~%
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~%

\begin{document} 

{\setlength{\parindent}{0 pt}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \centering
        \begin{axis}[
            width=0.90\textwidth,
            height=0.25\textheight,
            xlabel=$x$(mm),ylabel=$y$(m),zlabel=Vitesse(m/s),
            xmin=0,xmax=300,
            ymin=-0.0152,ymax=0.0152,
            xtick = {0,10,20,40,60,80,100,300},
            ytick distance = 0.005,
            ztick distance = 0.005,
            grid = both,
            area plot/.style={fill opacity=0.2},
            clip=true
            ]
        
        \addplot3[name path=X0  ,Red        ,area plot,smooth,mark=none,unbounded coords=jump]table[x expr=0,y=X0-Y,z=X0-Vitesse]           {Re100-X_000.dat};
        \addplot3[name path=X10 ,Orange     ,area plot,smooth,mark=none,unbounded coords=jump]table[x expr=10,y=X10-Y,z=X10-Vitesse]        {Re100-X_010.dat};  
        \addplot3[name path=X20 ,Yellow     ,area plot,smooth,mark=none,unbounded coords=jump]table[x expr=20,y=X20-Y,z=X20-Vitesse]        {Re100-X_020.dat};  
        \addplot3[name path=X40 ,YellowGreen,area plot,smooth,mark=none,unbounded coords=jump]table[x expr=40,y=X40-Y,z=X40-Vitesse]        {Re100-X_040.dat};  
        \addplot3[name path=X60 ,Green      ,area plot,smooth,mark=none,unbounded coords=jump]table[x expr=60,y=X60-Y,z=X60-Vitesse]        {Re100-X_060.dat};  
        \addplot3[name path=X80 ,OliveGreen ,area plot,smooth,mark=none,unbounded coords=jump]table[x expr=80,y=X80-Y,z=X80-Vitesse]        {Re100-X_080.dat};  
        \addplot3[name path=X100,Blue       ,area plot,smooth,mark=none,unbounded coords=jump]table[x expr=100,y=X100-Y,z=X100-Vitesse] {Re100-X_100.dat};
        \addplot3[name path=Out ,Purple     ,area plot,smooth,mark=none,unbounded coords=jump]table[x expr=300,y=Outlet-Y,z=Outlet-Vitesse]{Re100-X_Outlet.dat};        
        
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
}

{\setlength{\parindent}{0 pt}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \centering
        \begin{axis}[
            width=0.90\textwidth,
            height=0.25\textheight,
            xlabel=$x$(mm),ylabel=$y$(m),zlabel=Vorticité(m/s), 
            xmin=-100,xmax=300,
            ymin=-0.0152,ymax=0.0152,
            zmin=-10.5,zmax=10.5,
            xtick = {-100,0,10,20,40,60,80,100,300},
            ytick distance = 0.004,
            ztick distance = 2.5,
            grid = both,
            area plot/.style={fill opacity=0.2},
            ]
        
        \addplot3[fill=Sepia        ,area plot,smooth,mark=none,unbounded coords=jump]table[x expr=-100,y=Inlet-Y,z=Inlet-Vorticité]    {Re100-X_Inlet.dat};    
        \addplot3[fill=Red          ,area plot,smooth,mark=none,unbounded coords=jump]table[x expr=0,y=X0-Y,z=X0-Vorticité]             {Re100-X_000.dat};
        \addplot3[fill=Orange       ,area plot,smooth,mark=none,unbounded coords=jump]table[x expr=10,y=X10-Y,z=X10-Vorticité]          {Re100-X_010.dat};  
        \addplot3[fill=Yellow       ,area plot,smooth,mark=none,unbounded coords=jump]table[x expr=20,y=X20-Y,z=X20-Vorticité]          {Re100-X_020.dat};  
        \addplot3[fill=YellowGreen  ,area plot,smooth,mark=none,unbounded coords=jump]table[x expr=40,y=X40-Y,z=X40-Vorticité]          {Re100-X_040.dat};  
        \addplot3[fill=Green        ,area plot,smooth,mark=none,unbounded coords=jump]table[x expr=60,y=X60-Y,z=X60-Vorticité]          {Re100-X_060.dat};  
        \addplot3[fill=OliveGreen   ,area plot,smooth,mark=none,unbounded coords=jump]table[x expr=80,y=X80-Y,z=X80-Vorticité]          {Re100-X_080.dat};  
        \addplot3[fill=Blue         ,area plot,smooth,mark=none,unbounded coords=jump]table[x expr=100,y=X100-Y,z=X100-Vorticité]       {Re100-X_100.dat};
        \addplot3[fill=Purple       ,area plot,smooth,mark=none,unbounded coords=jump]table[x expr=300,y=Outlet-Y,z=Outlet-Vorticité]   {Re100-X_Outlet.dat};   

    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
}

{\setlength{\parindent}{0 pt}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \centering
        \begin{axis}[
            width=0.90\textwidth,
            height=0.25\textheight,
            xlabel=$x$(mm),ylabel=$y$(m),zlabel=Vitesse(m/s),
            xmin=0,xmax=300,
            ymin=-0.0152,ymax=0.0152,
            xtick = {0,10,20,40,60,80,100,300},
            ytick distance = 0.005,
            ztick distance = 0.005,
            grid = both,
            area plot/.style={fill opacity=0.2},
            clip=true
            ]
        
        \addplot3[name path=X0  ,Red        ,area plot,smooth,mark=none,unbounded coords=jump]table[x expr=0,y=X0-Y,z=X0-Vitesse]           {Re100-X_000.dat};
        \addplot3[name path=X10 ,Orange     ,area plot,smooth,mark=none,unbounded coords=jump]table[x expr=10,y=X10-Y,z=X10-Vitesse]        {Re100-X_010.dat};  
        \addplot3[name path=X20 ,Yellow     ,area plot,smooth,mark=none,unbounded coords=jump]table[x expr=20,y=X20-Y,z=X20-Vitesse]        {Re100-X_020.dat};  
        \addplot3[name path=X40 ,YellowGreen,area plot,smooth,mark=none,unbounded coords=jump]table[x expr=40,y=X40-Y,z=X40-Vitesse]        {Re100-X_040.dat};  
        \addplot3[name path=X60 ,Green      ,area plot,smooth,mark=none,unbounded coords=jump]table[x expr=60,y=X60-Y,z=X60-Vitesse]        {Re100-X_060.dat};  
        \addplot3[name path=X80 ,OliveGreen ,area plot,smooth,mark=none,unbounded coords=jump]table[x expr=80,y=X80-Y,z=X80-Vitesse]        {Re100-X_080.dat};  
        \addplot3[name path=X100,Blue       ,area plot,smooth,mark=none,unbounded coords=jump]table[x expr=100,y=X100-Y,z=X100-Vitesse]     {Re100-X_100.dat};
        \addplot3[name path=Out ,Purple     ,area plot,smooth,mark=none,unbounded coords=jump]table[x expr=300,y=Outlet-Y,z=Outlet-Vitesse] {Re100-X_Outlet.dat};   
                
        \addplot3[name path=Zero,White      ,area plot,mark=none,unbounded coords=jump]coordinates{(0,0.015,0)(100,0.015,0)(100,-0.015,0)(0,-0.015,0)};
                
        \addplot[Red        ,opacity=0.2]fill between[of=X0     and Zero];      
        \addplot[Orange     ,opacity=0.2]fill between[of=X10    and Zero];      
        \addplot[Yellow     ,opacity=0.2]fill between[of=X20    and Zero];      
        \addplot[YellowGreen,opacity=0.2]fill between[of=X40    and Zero];      
        \addplot[Green      ,opacity=0.2]fill between[of=X60    and Zero];      
        \addplot[OliveGreen ,opacity=0.2]fill between[of=X80    and Zero];      
        \addplot[Blue       ,opacity=0.2]fill between[of=X100   and Zero];      
        \addplot[Purple     ,opacity=0.2]fill between[of=Out    and Zero];      
        
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
}

\end{document}
    

And below is what one of my .dat looks like, it is the data to create the red curve on the second image (file name is Re100-X_000.dat) :
X0-Y        X0-Vorticité    X0-Pression X0-Vitesse
-0.014829583    -10.725614  0.075275898 0.001921865
-0.014488751    -8.063652   0.086036734 0.005041101
-0.014147919    -6.109499   0.10102057  0.007468608
-0.013807088    -4.4875669  0.11603978  0.00929632
-0.013466258    -3.2518559  0.12909602  0.010648998
-0.013125429    -2.4377155  0.13975942  0.011655281
-0.012704461    -1.7564065  0.1502538   0.012594134
-0.012203367    -1.2934237  0.15997419  0.013441452
-0.011702305    -1.0630168  0.16812676  0.014153937
-0.011201279    -0.91729301 0.17528585  0.014795009
-0.010700294    -0.80379403 0.18178511  0.015397052
-0.010199357    -0.7039448  0.18768154  0.015973406
-0.009698477    -0.61384743 0.19301969  0.016534418
-0.009197665    -0.53798443 0.19782622  0.017090401
-0.008696934    -0.48080158 0.20217606  0.017655095
-0.008196302    -0.39852846 0.20600481  0.01823524
-0.007695792    -0.056509256    0.20818374  0.018787939
-0.007195436    1.0833504   0.20500027  0.019115007
-0.006695274    2.9533067   0.18752138  0.018822301
-0.006246665    8.6130114   0.14484204  0.017053183
-0.005895403    13.710161   0.088010892 0.013879864
-0.005625334    16.840977   0.039758503 0.010263154
-0.005417682    17.890705   0.008843864 0.00697213
-0.005258016    17.742121   -0.007742522    0.00429956
-0.005135239    17.13258    -0.015521631    0.002237015
-0.005040823    16.531435   -0.018378658    0.000673141
0.00504014  -15.8211    -0.026680201    0.000688762
0.005140974 -16.433819  -0.023812089    0.002297927
0.005272056 -17.105461  -0.015630394    0.00444251
0.005442455 -17.248516  0.002196882 0.007242653
0.005663966 -16.009602  0.035634812 0.010678818
0.005951918 -12.543624  0.086749583 0.014354617
0.006326238 -7.1234474  0.1428248   0.017337596
0.00680403  -1.8027315  0.17911838  0.018679777
0.007242238 -0.69145471 0.19111066  0.018632382
0.007508298 -1.037151   0.18852749  0.018697094
0.007868229 0.08423692  0.19182536  0.018359348
0.008400037 0.43894482  0.18938023  0.017762251
0.008932026 0.52147388  0.18517163  0.017127907
0.009464161 0.58462614  0.18040988  0.016505139
0.009996416 0.67231882  0.17512307  0.015885303
0.010528771 0.7774353   0.1692175   0.015252391
0.011061211 0.89722133  0.16265909  0.014593926
0.011593722 1.0458665   0.15535347  0.013893929
0.012126295 1.2688731   0.1471037   0.013123672
0.01265892  1.67794     0.13721925  0.012212311
0.01319159  2.6183777   0.12456862  0.011015384
0.01358645  3.773562    0.11184071  0.009721323
0.013843475 4.4860325   0.10239352  0.008665334
0.014100494 5.6117549   0.092071839 0.007352551
0.014357504 6.9289842   0.081588358 0.005731065
0.014614508 8.4013405   0.072291516 0.003755704
0.014871505 10.397785   0.066216446 0.001390265




First I got the data to be represented as simple curves in several yz-plane, which worked quite well :




Then I learned about area plot but wasn't satisfied with it sonce it fill the space from the starting point to the ending point of the function, and not between the curve and the xy plane (or the z=0 if you will). It is another .dat file but the problem is just enhanced here, and occurs on all graphs :




Finally I stumbled accross several methods, all of which didn't work as intended for unknown reasons, either causing errors or unwanted results. The best I could get is the following, with the fill between plotting :



So I'm looking for a method to fill this space between my curves and the z=0 plane, or in other word, I want to fill a space between the curve and its y axis, only on the xy plane it is placed on. Any help would be highly appreciated, I can provide more code if needed, thank you in advance. Also here are the main sources I used to get those results :

tikz.dev
sqlpac.com
latexdraw.com
overleaf.com


Can you put your code snippets together into something people can copy-paste-compile? Also, please minimise your preamble to include only the packages necessary for your question. Doing these things will make it much easier for people trying to help. Right now, nobody can look at this but you: we don't have a sample .dat to play with.

@cfr here it is, thanks for your comment. Please tell me if you need anything else

In the end, I found a proper solution, which is not ideal because it requires two more lines of code per curve, but good enough, here is the final MWE :
\documentclass[french]{article}         %
  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                         %
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}                     %
\usepackage{tikz}                                   %
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,plotmarks,3d}
\usepackage{graphicx,float}                         %
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{pgfplots}                               %
\usepgfmodule{plot}                                 %
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}                           %
                                                    %
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={             %
                    label style={font=\tiny},       %
                    tick label style={font=\tiny},  %
                    legend style={font=\tiny}       %
                    }}  

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \centering
        \begin{axis}[
            xlabel=$x$(mm),ylabel=$y$(m),zlabel=Pression,   %
            xmin=-100,xmax=300,
            ymin=-0.0152,ymax=0.0152,
            zmin=-0.03,
            xtick distance = 100,
            ytick distance = 0.004,
            ztick distance = 0.05,
            grid = both,
            area plot/.style={fill opacity=0.2},
            ]
            
        \addplot3[name path=X0          ,Red    ,area plot,smooth,mark=none,unbounded coords=jump]table[x expr=0,y=X0-Y,z=X0-Pression]  {Re100-X_000.dat};
        \addplot3[name path=Z0  ,dotted ,White  ,area plot,smooth,mark=none,unbounded coords=jump]table[x expr=0,y=Oy,z=Oz]             {Re100-X_000.dat};
        
        \addplot[Red,opacity=0.2]fill between[of=X0 and Z0];        

    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

From Daniel N's comment, I deduced we could add two columns in the file, to be able to draw a line at z=0 between two y's values (the dotted one) so we can fill the space between the curve and this line with fill between :
X0-Y        X0-Vorticité    X0-Pression X0-Vitesse  Oy  Oz
-0.014829583    -10.725614  0.075275898 0.001921865 -0.015  0
-0.014488751    -8.063652   0.086036734 0.005041101 0.015   0
-0.014147919    -6.109499   0.10102057  0.007468608
-0.013807088    -4.4875669  0.11603978  0.00929632
-0.013466258    -3.2518559  0.12909602  0.010648998
-0.013125429    -2.4377155  0.13975942  0.011655281
-0.012704461    -1.7564065  0.1502538   0.012594134
-0.012203367    -1.2934237  0.15997419  0.013441452
-0.011702305    -1.0630168  0.16812676  0.014153937
-0.011201279    -0.91729301 0.17528585  0.014795009
-0.010700294    -0.80379403 0.18178511  0.015397052
-0.010199357    -0.7039448  0.18768154  0.015973406
-0.009698477    -0.61384743 0.19301969  0.016534418
-0.009197665    -0.53798443 0.19782622  0.017090401
-0.008696934    -0.48080158 0.20217606  0.017655095
-0.008196302    -0.39852846 0.20600481  0.01823524
-0.007695792    -0.056509256    0.20818374  0.018787939
-0.007195436    1.0833504   0.20500027  0.019115007
-0.006695274    2.9533067   0.18752138  0.018822301
-0.006246665    8.6130114   0.14484204  0.017053183
-0.005895403    13.710161   0.088010892 0.013879864
-0.005625334    16.840977   0.039758503 0.010263154
-0.005417682    17.890705   0.008843864 0.00697213
-0.005258016    17.742121   -0.007742522    0.00429956
-0.005135239    17.13258    -0.015521631    0.002237015
-0.005040823    16.531435   -0.018378658    0.000673141
0.00504014  -15.8211    -0.026680201    0.000688762
0.005140974 -16.433819  -0.023812089    0.002297927
0.005272056 -17.105461  -0.015630394    0.00444251
0.005442455 -17.248516  0.002196882 0.007242653
0.005663966 -16.009602  0.035634812 0.010678818
0.005951918 -12.543624  0.086749583 0.014354617
0.006326238 -7.1234474  0.1428248   0.017337596
0.00680403  -1.8027315  0.17911838  0.018679777
0.007242238 -0.69145471 0.19111066  0.018632382
0.007508298 -1.037151   0.18852749  0.018697094
0.007868229 0.08423692  0.19182536  0.018359348
0.008400037 0.43894482  0.18938023  0.017762251
0.008932026 0.52147388  0.18517163  0.017127907
0.009464161 0.58462614  0.18040988  0.016505139
0.009996416 0.67231882  0.17512307  0.015885303
0.010528771 0.7774353   0.1692175   0.015252391
0.011061211 0.89722133  0.16265909  0.014593926
0.011593722 1.0458665   0.15535347  0.013893929
0.012126295 1.2688731   0.1471037   0.013123672
0.01265892  1.67794     0.13721925  0.012212311
0.01319159  2.6183777   0.12456862  0.011015384
0.01358645  3.773562    0.11184071  0.009721323
0.013843475 4.4860325   0.10239352  0.008665334
0.014100494 5.6117549   0.092071839 0.007352551
0.014357504 6.9289842   0.081588358 0.005731065
0.014614508 8.4013405   0.072291516 0.003755704
0.014871505 10.397785   0.066216446 0.001390265




If this is what you are looking for, you need only to use fill=red, in the corresponding drawing instruction \addplot3.  To fill the whole area between the curve and the Oy axis in the Oyz plane, it is sufficient to add two fake data in the file:

the first line: -0.014829583    -10.725614  0.075275898 0
the last line: 0.014871505 10.397785   0.066216446 0

The figure below is obtained without changing the file.

Since I have the impression that your code is unnormally complex (what are the necessary libraries), I'm answering the question instead of posting a comment.  Note that I changed the name of the file (and also replaced the French é with a normal e in your .dat file to avoid compilation errors).
The code
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
% \usepackage{tikz}   
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usepgfmodule{plot}   
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}       
  
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={   
    label style={font=\tiny},       
    tick label style={font=\tiny},  
    legend style={font=\tiny}       
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[%
    % width=0.90\textwidth,
    % height=0.4\textheight,
    xlabel=$x$(mm), ylabel=$y$(m), zlabel=Vitesse(m/s),
    xmin=-1, xmax=3,
    ymin=-0.0152, ymax=0.0152,
    % xtick = {0, 10, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 300},
    ytick distance = 0.005,
    ztick distance = 0.005,
    grid = both,
    area plot/.style={fill opacity=0.2},
    clip=true
    ]
    
    \addplot3[
    fill=red,
    name path=X0, red,
    area plot,
    smooth, mark=none,
    unbounded coords=jump,
    ]
    table[x expr=0, y=X0-Y, z=X0-Vitesse]  {inSpaceRed.dat};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Thank you Daniel, unfortunatly I already tried this option and this result is equivalent to the second try I made (second picture also). The fill=red otpion only fills the space between the curve and a line joining the first and last points of the curve. What I am looking for is to fill the space between the curve and the xy-plane at z=0.

Can you or want you to modify the .dat files?  What you want to obtain corresponds to a graph that starts at (y_min, 0) and ends at (y_max, 0).

I modified the answer to see what will happen adding two more lines to the .dat file.

I like that as a temporary solution, thanks. However, there are some other .dat files in which the method distorts the curves. I am wondering if drawing an "invisible" line for each curve could resolve that, using the fill between method, I'll keep you up to date about that.

I don't understand how the curve might be distorted if you construct only the projection of the borders on the first coordinate axis.  Anyway, I think that the data in the "red" file is notcompletly ordered (in y).  If the curves are really graphs, than you must order the points.

Adding 2 lines to the file add points on the curve, which extreme data's not always equal zero. Thus, adding those points makes the plain curve go straight to zero from the point just before.
